# Three-Color Coding based on Date Ranges in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

Follow-up to [594140](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/590914/color-coding-sharepoint-online-library-by-date-ran.html?childToView=594140)

ORIGINAL CODE:

```
{
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
"elmType": "div",
"txtContent": "@currentField",
"style": {
"background-color": "=if(@currentField <= @now + 864000000, 'red', if(@currentField <= @now + 7776000000, 'yellow', ''))"
}
}
```

My boss is, of course, never satisfied with a solution that works. Now she wants three colors for three conditions:

- Next Review <90 days from 'now' = yellow
- Next Review <10 days from 'now' = orange
- expired (Next Review is past 'now') = red

You'd think this would be simple. You'd think it would be a matter of copy/pasting a third condition into the "background color" section and changing the time and color values, right? No such luck.

Here's what I tried:

NEW CODE:

```
{
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
"elmType": "div",
"txtContent": "@currentField",
"style": {
"background-color": "=if(@currentField <= @now, 'red', =if(@currentField <= @now + 864000000, 'orange', if(@currentField <= @now + 7776000000, 'yellow', ''))"
}
}
```

Everything looks right. I even ran it through an online JSON code validator to make sure no formatting got messed up. But now the column is utterly blank--no color, and no values either!

This makes no sense. There's no conceivable way that background-color instructions, even bad ones, could erase the contents of the cells! What's going on here?

Comment: Try my answer given below & let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is syntax error in your conditions against `background-color`. Try using below JSON code, it should work for you:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "@currentField",
    "style": {
       "background-color": "=if(@currentField <= @now, 'red', if(@currentField <= @now + 864000000, 'orange', if(@currentField <= @now + 7776000000, 'yellow', '')))"
    }
}
```

**official documentation**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

Comment: That seems to work, though I can't spot the difference. Thanks!

Comment: You had an extra `=` in 2nd condition & you missed one closing bracket `)` at the end.